# Sometimes GestureDetector is skipping onFling

Tags: android, gesture, onfling

I have an application which uses GestureDetector and I am replacing some images onDown and onFling (aka onUp). However in some cases onFling is not called and the outcome is not pretty :)

Have you faced such issue and have you found a fix/workaround(besides using a timeout)?
Here is a little code:

```
    final GestureDetector gdt1 = new GestureDetector(getApplicationContext(), new MyGestureDetector(mGestDetector, R.id.weatherFrame1));
    FrameLayout weatherFrame1 = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.weatherFrame1);
    if (weatherFrame1 != null)
    {
        weatherFrame1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener()
        {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(final View view, final MotionEvent event)
            {
                gdt1.onTouchEvent(event);
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
```

And here is part of MyGestureDetector.java

```
    public class MyGestureDetector implements GestureDetector.OnGestureListener{
    {
    ...
        @Override
        public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e)
        {
            int index = e.getActionIndex();
            int pointerId = e.getPointerId(index);

            if (startingPointerId == -1)
            {
                Log.i("MyGestureDetector", "Pointer is " + pointerId);

                if (pointerId == 0)
                {
                    startingPosX = e.getX(pointerId);
                    startingPosY = e.getY(pointerId);
                    startingPointerId = pointerId;
                    if (null != mGestureListener)
                    {
                        mGestureListener.onDown(mGestureOrigin);
                    }
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY)
        {
            startingPointerId = -1;
            if (null != mGestureListener)
            {
                mGestureListener.onUp(mGestureOrigin);
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: post the code you have worked so far.

Comment: Is view with gesture listener and view which you drag is same view? If yes just create view over your dragable view and set gesture listener on your new overlay view

Comment: @ErvinMartirosyan Actually I am using onFling() to detect onUp() event, because according to the onFling() official docs
`Notified of a fling event when it occurs with the initial on down MotionEvent and the matching up MotionEvent.` There is no dragging necessary for my case, only down and up events.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For detecting "up" and "down" events, I would recommend something simple like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(final View view, final MotionEvent event) {

   if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
      // handle up event
   } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
      // handle down event
   }

}
```

**Edit**: The most likely reason `onFling` isn't being called every time is because it isn't simply a way to handle UP events. Looking at the Android source code, `onFling` is only called when the velocity reaches the minimum velocity required to be considered a "fling." Check it out:

```
 case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        mStillDown = false;
        MotionEvent currentUpEvent = MotionEvent.obtain(ev);
        if (mIsDoubleTapping) {
            // Finally, give the up event of the double-tap
            handled |= mDoubleTapListener.onDoubleTapEvent(ev);
        } else if (mInLongPress) {
            mHandler.removeMessages(TAP);
            mInLongPress = false;
        } else if (mAlwaysInTapRegion) {
            handled = mListener.onSingleTapUp(ev);
        } else {

            // A fling must travel the minimum tap distance
            final VelocityTracker velocityTracker = mVelocityTracker;
            velocityTracker.computeCurrentVelocity(1000, mMaximumFlingVelocity);
            final float velocityY = velocityTracker.getYVelocity();
            final float velocityX = velocityTracker.getXVelocity();

            if ((Math.abs(velocityY) > mMinimumFlingVelocity)
                    || (Math.abs(velocityX) > mMinimumFlingVelocity)){
                handled = mListener.onFling(mCurrentDownEvent, ev, velocityX, velocityY);
            }
        }
```

Most notably:

```
 if ((Math.abs(velocityY) > mMinimumFlingVelocity)
          || (Math.abs(velocityX) > mMinimumFlingVelocity)){
      handled = mListener.onFling(mCurrentDownEvent, ev, velocityX, velocityY);
 }
```

(Source: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.1.1_r1/android/view/GestureDetector.java)

Comment: I guess this will be the best approach, but still this does not give an answer to my issue with onFling not being called.

Comment: Check out the additional info I added to the answer. onFling doesn't necessarily get called for every UP event.

Comment: Even though I am not 100% sure that onFling is not called because of the velocity being too low (I need to see(debug) it to believe it ;)), this is the most logical reason for my issue.